# Oracle - AUTHENTICATION_DATA

Tags: sql, oracle

What is a valid value of AUTHENTICATION_DATA parameter? Currently, when I'm trying to issue following query the result is empty string:

`SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'AUTHENTICATION_DATA') FROM DUAL;`

AUTHENTICATION_METHOD is set to "password".

Comment: [This is in the documentation.](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions199.htm#r5c1-t265)

Comment: @AlexPoole can you elaborate? I saw this particular part of documentation several times, however, I'm not sure how this brings me closer to the answer.

Comment: *"Data being used to authenticate the login user. For X.503 certificate authenticated sessions, this field returns the context of the certificate in HEX2 format."* implies that it is probably specific to sessions authenticated with X.503 certificates; if your session is not using this system, it is expected to be blank.

Comment: It seems to always be blank in v12.1 but does work in v12.2.  When TCPS is used, it's filled in (1918 chars in an example I have) but I have no idea what format 'HEX2' it is, nor what contents of the cert it is supposed to be (just the public key or a digest of the whole cert or ?).